# Find the Fourier Series of $e^x$

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

Hello I am having some issues the following fourier series $$f(x)=e^{x}, -\pi<x<\pi $$
I have no issues with the immediate  steps, solving for $a_n$  and $ b_n $, i believe that I am having some algebra simplification.

for the $a_n$ term I get

$$ \int e^{x}\cos(nx)= \frac {1}{n^{2}+1}({(-1)^{n}}(e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi})$$

where as the answer should be 
$$ \int e^{x}\cos(nx)= \frac {{(-1)^{n}}(e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi})}{\pi(n^{2}+1)}$$

here is the work i did, i not one term because it is equal to zero

$$\frac{1}{\pi}e^{x}\cos(nx)= \frac{1}{\pi}[e^{x}\cos(nx) -n^{2}\int e^{x}\cos(nx)] $$

now when i simplify it

$$ \frac{1+n^{2}}{\pi} \int e^{x}\cos(nx) = \frac{1}{\pi}[e^{x}\cos(nx)] $$
 can you see where i went wrong?

Comment: Only a factor $\frac{1}{\pi}$ differs form an expression to the other one. Are you sure that you did not forget any normalization factor when you calculated your $an(f)$ ?

Comment: Perfect! Now, just notice that $a_{n}\left(f\right)$ is $$\frac{1}{\pi}\intop_{-\pi}^{\pi}f\left(x\right)\cos\left(nx\right)dx.$$

Comment: so after find the $a_n$ term I still have to multiple it by $\frac{1}{\pi}$?

Comment: The definition of the $a_{n}\left(f\right)$ is with the factor $\frac{1}{\pi}$. What you calculated is actually $\pi a_{n}\left(f\right)$ when the period of the function $f$ is $2\pi$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series for example).

Answer (score 1):

For $a_0$ we get:

\begin{align}
a_0&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^x d x=\frac{1}{\pi}[e^x]_{-\pi}^{\pi} \\\\
&=\frac{e^{\pi}-e^{-\pi}}{\pi}=\frac{2 \sinh (\pi)}{\pi}
\end{align}

For $a_n$ we get (using two times integration by parts):
\begin{align}
a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^x \cos (nx) dx=\frac{2(n \cosh(\pi) \sin (n\pi)+\cos(n\pi)\sinh(\pi))}{1+n^2}
\end{align}

For $b_n$ we get (using two times integration by parts):
\begin{align}
b_n&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^x \sin(nx) dx = \frac{2(\cosh(\pi)\sin(n\pi)-n\cos(n\pi)\sinh(\pi))}{1+n^2}
\end{align}